# Remote apps instead of a remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, remoteapp

I wanted to check on some software I used 10+ years ago and see if it is still available.
I'm not after specific programs, more the name for this kind of technology.

Basically the remote desktop platform (it would have been either MS or Citrix remote desktop) had a feature that let you create shortcut icons on the client computers desktop/start menu for programs that were available within the remote hosted desktop.

Once you had those icons on your own actual desktop, it was possible to load these shortcuts and instead of a full remote desktop starting up with that program then loading within it, instead just the remote program itself would appear in the window.   Basically simulating as accurately as possible what the program would look like if you were running it locally.

So my question is, is this kind of tech still possible in todays remote desktop solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both features are still available.

MS RDS - RemoteApp
Citrix Virtual Apps and Desktops - Published Application